# what is static objective function

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

Paper on [Adam](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf) mentions Stationary Objective function. I am not able to find its definition on Internet (or may be it's there with some other name and I am not able to figure it out). I will be grateful If someone can describe or direct me to the right resource.

Answer (score 0):

A stationary point of a function is typically a local minimum or maximum, i.e. the gradient is zero, think of a parabola’s minimum.
A stationary function would be a function that is constant wrt. some partial derivative. So for an objective function for a neural network, the cost or objective function is zero when the minimum is found. I believe that when they refer to a stationary objective function in the paper, they mean a function whose partial derivative with respect to the parameters of the network is constant.

Comment: Thanks @brewmaster321 . Please allow me sometime to check what you have mentioned whether it fits with author's analysis. If it does, I will accept your answer. Thank you.